# Custom MIME Type for PHP File

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mime

Okay, so I have a weird one for you all today. I'm looking into creating a custom MIME type for a .php file. I've read some pro's/con's on this and it won't be for much other than some experimentation to see what can really be done. My company's initials are TTP and so we decided it'd be kinda fun to have all of our .php pages re-written to a custom .ttp extension. I've attempted my normal cPanel X route with adding it in, and I've also tried adding the change into the .htaccess file. It work's perfectly fine until I change the application type to anything php.

```
AddType text/html ttp  // works
AddType text/x-php ttp // doesn't work
AddType application/x-php ttp // doesn't work
AddType application/x-http-php ttp // doesn't work
```

Some things that have come up was an issue that doing this renders the .php file and therefore makes it difficult for the browser to decide how to handle it. Any other ideas? I'm pretty sure that at the end of the day this won't be something the company will do, but they wanted to see if any experiment I could run will work.

Comment: Applying standard mime types to non-standard file extensions is rather different from having a custom mime type.

Comment: I tried that about a decade ago. Google dropped the site from its indexes entirely. When I went back to a common file extension (a couple of months later) it reappeared. Even if that isn't a problem these days, having cute characters on the end of URLs is going to confuse (some) people who try to type them. I really wouldn't bother.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think it won't be good in any shape/form for a web hosting and developing company. We specialize in SEO and I'm pretty sure that .ttp is going to mess up some of our optimization we work hard for here. I guess I'm giving it a go so I can at least show people it's somewhat do-able, and then have a reasonable explanation as to why it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't handle PHP.  Content-Type doesn't matter here.

Look at your CGI or module configuration, to configure PHP to handle more than .php.  For PHP as a module:

```
<FilesMatch \.ttp$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are specified with `AddHandler`. The mod_php handler is `php5-script`.

And the browser never handles PHP.