# HTML form submit button displays the php code instead of executing it

Tags: php, forms, xhtml

I've just written my first form using HTML by taking a template for a php emailing form from another site. When I enter all the data, though, it just displays the php page instead of executing the script.

```
            <form action="template1.php" method="post">
            <p style="padding-top: 5px;" id="form_header">
                Fill out variable information below:
            </p>
            <table width="260px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px">
                        Customer name:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="toName" type="text" size="45" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px">
                        Customer e-mail address:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="toEmail" type="text" size="45" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px">
                        From name:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="fromName" type="text" size="45" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px;">
                        From e-mail address:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="fromEmail" type="text" size="45" value="place@holder.com" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="reason_boxes" width="260px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 70px; height: 30px;">
                        Reason:
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 0 4px 4px 4px; vertical-align: center;">
                        <input type="radio" name="reason" value="credit"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 1px 0 4px 4px; vertical-align: center;">
                        Insufficient credit.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px; width: 70px; height: 100px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        <input type="radio" name="reason" value="credit"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        Software based POS systems and/or Payment Jack processing units do not qualify. We will continue to make enhancements to this service and hope to be able to offer this in the future.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px; width: 70px; height: 100px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        <input type="radio" name="reason" value="credit"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        Mail order/telephone order and/or internet based business does not qualify. We will continue to make enhancements to this service and hope to be able to offer this in the future.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px; width: 70px; height: 70px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        <input type="radio" name="reason" value="credit"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                        The average ticket requested currently exceeds the parameters established for this program.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 14px; height: 50px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 4px;">
                    </td>                        
                    <td style="padding: 4px; text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom;">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Email" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

And the PHP

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['toEmail'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED 
    $email_to = $_POST['toName'];;
    $email_subject = "This is a test";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['toName']) ||
        !isset($_POST['toEmail']) ||
        !isset($_POST['fromName']) ||
        !isset($_POST['fromEmail'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $to_name = $_POST['toName']; // required
    $to_email = $_POST['toEmail']; // required
    $from_name = $_POST['fromName']; // required
    $from_email = $_POST['fromEmail']; //  required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$to_email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The \'to\' email address you entered for the customer does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$from_email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The \'from\' email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$toName)) {

    $error_message .= 'The first name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$toEmail)) {

    $error_message .= 'The last name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "toName: ".clean_string($toName)."\n";

    $email_message .= "toName: ".clean_string($toEmail)."\n";

    $email_message .= "fromName: ".clean_string($fromName)."\n";

    $email_message .= "fromEmail: ".clean_string($fromEmail)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$from_name."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$from_email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does your server support PHP and is it properly configured?

Comment: Nope. I was trying to run it off the desktop and a quick google search revealed that's not going to work. Thank you. =)

Comment: Yeah that's definitely not going to work

Comment: Yeah, check out **[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)** for a easy install to get you up and going.

Comment: Had the same problem as well. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsmMVwz1rlo) had a quick solution to setting up a server to run php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your server does not have php installed. If its installed check server settings for mime types. Extension .php needs to be mapped correctly.

Here is an example of setting mime type for extension: [Custom MIME Type for PHP File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435237/custom-mime-type-for-php-file)